# Can't change variable in method C#

Tags: c#, class, methods

Ok, so I'm trying to make this small console game, and I'm using a class I made named `position` for both enemies and for the player. `position` contains both an `x` and a `y` value. To move, I'm making a method - first I made it only for the player, but now I'm trying to make it work for every position.

```
    public static void move2(int x, int y, position pos)
    {
        position newpos = new position()
        {
            X = pos.X + x,
            Y = pos.Y + y
        };
        if (possiblemove(newpos))
        {
            pos = newpos;
            Console.WriteLine("    " + pos.X +" "+ pos.Y + "<old pos - new pos >" + newpos.X +" " + newpos.Y);
            Console.ReadLine();
```

The thing is, when I try to set `pos` to `newpos`, it doesn't change and stays with the same values as before. Even though I wrote `pos = newpos`, the writeline gives me 2 different values. If I use a position, like my `playerpos`, instead if a variable it works just fine.

I'm quite new at programming and have no idea why this is.

If there's a way to fix it I'm open to suggestions, that's why I posted it here in the first place.

Comment: Is `posistion` a class or a struct?

Comment: Show the definition of `position`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the simplest way to refactor your code to achieve what you're after, might be replacing this line:

```
pos = newpos;
```

with something like this:

```
pos.X = newpos.X;
pos.Y = newpos.Y;
```

Answer (score 2):

When you pass a reference type into method without `ref` keyword, that method can modify your object (add or remove items in passed list for example), but can not reassign it to another object. 
It means that caller will always access the same object (even modified by method) before and after the method call.
 As Tim mentioned, adding `ref` keyword changes this, so then reference can also be changed.

Answer (score 1):

`pos` is not being passed by reference, so setting it to a new value only changed the local reference to it within `move2`.  Consider passing it by reference instead:

```
public static void move2(int x, int y, ref posistion pos)
```

you'll have to add `ref` to your calling code, too

Comment: It looks like he's logging it in the same function, `move2`.

Comment: @Amy Yes, but most likely `pos` is struct therefore its value doesn't exists outside `move2` scope

Comment: @kuskmen Why does "outside `move2` scope" *matter* if he's logging it within the function?

Comment: I may have misunderstood the question-- waiting to see if there are any updates from the OP...

Comment: posistions just contains a public static int x get set and a public static int y get set.

Comment: @kuskmen pos is just a parameter only used in this method

Comment: @Jacobhoem It's STATIC!  That's your problem.  Remove the static keyword.  You really should add the definition of `posistion` to the question so you can get a proper answer.

Comment: @amy Removing the static part did nothing ,still didnt work. However changing it ti c.X = newpos.X;  c.Y = newpos.Y; seems to have worked.

Comment: @Jacobhoem Okay I'm at a complete loss then.  I couldn't reproduce your issue to begin with, unless its the static keyword at play.  Glad you got it solved.

Answer (score 0):

Can you post the definition of your Position class/struct? I just wrote out your code nearly as-is and it works as expected for me.

It may also help to see the code near where you call the Move method, in case you're declaring the original variable oddly.

```
namespace PositionTest
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args) {
            Position mobpos = new Position { X = 1, Y = 2 };
            move(1, 4, mobpos);
        }

        public static void move(int x, int y, Position pos) {
            Position newpos = new Position { X = pos.X + x, Y = pos.Y + y };

            pos = newpos;
            Console.WriteLine("    " + pos.X + " " + pos.Y + "<old pos - new pos >" + newpos.X + " " + newpos.Y);
            Console.ReadLine();
        }

    }

    class Position
    {
        public int X { get; set; }
        public int Y { get; set; }
    }
}

Output:     2 6<old pos - new pos >2 6
```

**EDIT:** From one of your comments, I see you declared the Position's X and Y properties as static. Remove the static keyword, and your program may work.

Answer (score 0):

Because your class `X`/`Y` are static properties, as indicated in your comments on Tim's answer, all instances of `posistion` will share the *same* values of X and Y.  Consider this:

```
posistion posA = new posistion
{
    X = 1,
    Y = 2
};

posistion posB = new posistion
{
    X = 3,
    Y = 4
};

Console.Writeline($"{posA.X}/{posA.Y} - {posB.X}/{posB.Y}")
```

What do you expect the output to be?  Well, intuitively speaking, it *should* be `1/2 - 3/4`, right?  But if this is your definition of `posistion`:

```
public class posistion
{
    public static X { get; set; }
    public static Y { get; set; }
}
```

That is *not* the behavior you will observe from the first snippet of code.  What happens is, you create the first instance and its properties are `1` and `2`.  But when you create the second instance, it shares the same properties as every other instance because the properties are `static`... so it overwrites the properties in every other instance of `posistion` (because they all share the same property).

Try removing the `static` keyword from the definition of `X` and see what happens.  Each instance will have a *different* `X`!

So what is happening in your code?  You're creating `newPos` with new values... and these values *overwrite* the values in `pos`, rendering each indistinguishable from the other.

The proper fix here is to a) learn how `static` works, and b) remove the `static` keyword.